# Using setState with onChange does not update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, onchange, setstate

**What am I looking for?**
A way to use `setState()` on an `input` element that updates my `state` immediately with `onChange`.

**What have I done so far?**

I have two components, `BooksApp` and `SearchBook`. I am passing `result` to `SearchBook` as a prop to be rendered. Then I am capturing the changes on the `input` element using `onChange`. The `onChange` is calling the method I passed as a prop as well. 
React [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) says the following, but if I use a callback and then in the callback I invoke `setState()` it sounds to me that I am back at the same situation, because `setState()` will again be async:

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater, callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous state, read about the updater argument below.

**What is the issue?**
If the user erases the content of the `input` too quickly, although there is still a `console.log('empty')` in the console, the `setState()` does not run and thus `result` stays the same and does not become an empty array.

This is the content of `App.js`:

```
class BooksApp extends Component {
  state = {
    books: [],
    result: [],
    query: ''
  }
  updateQuery = (query) => {
    this.setState({ query: query.trim() })
  }
  objDigger = (arr, diggers) => {
    const digged = [];
    diggers.forEach((d) => {
      let o = {};
      o = arr.filter((a) => a.id === d);
      o.forEach((i) => {
        digged.push(i);
      })
    });
    return digged;
  }
  filterHelper = (result) => {
    const resultKeys = result.map((r) => r.id)
    const stateKeys = this.state.books.map((s) => s.id)
    // this.objDigger(this.state.books, stateKeys)

    // new books
    const newKeys = _array.difference(resultKeys, stateKeys);
    const newObjs = this.objDigger(result, newKeys)

    // existing books
    const existingKeys = _array.difference(resultKeys, newKeys)
    const existingObjs = this.objDigger(this.state.books, existingKeys);

    // search books
    const searchObjs = newObjs.concat(existingObjs);
    return searchObjs;
  }
  searchBook = (query) => {
    this.updateQuery(query);
    if (query) {
      BooksAPI.search(query).then((result) => {
        result = this.filterHelper(result)
        if (!result.error) {
          this.setState({
            result,
          })
        }
      })
    } else {
      console.log('empty');
      this.setState(state => ({
        result: []
      }));
    }
  }
  appHandleChange = (query) => {
    console.log('searching');
    this.searchBook(query);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <Route path="/search" render={() => (
          <SearchBook
            result={ this.state.result }
            onChange={ this.appHandleChange }
            onChangeShelf={ this.changeShelf }/>
        )}>
        </Route>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This is the content of `SearchBook`:

```
class SearchBook extends Component {
  handleChange = (book, newShelf) => {
    this.props.onChangeShelf(book, newShelf);
  }
  handleInputChange = (event) => {
    this.props.onChange(event.target.value);
  }
  render() {
    const { result } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="search-books">
        <div className="search-books-bar">
          <Link
            to="/"
            className="close-search"
          >
            Close
          </Link>
          <div className="search-books-input-wrapper">
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search by title or author"
              onChange={ (event) => this.handleInputChange(event) }
            />

          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="search-books-results">
          <ol className="books-grid">
            {result.length>0 && result.map((book) => (
              <li key={book.id}>
                <div className="book">
                  <div className="book-top">
                    <div className="book-cover" style={{ width: 128, height: 193, backgroundImage: `url(${book.imageLinks && book.imageLinks.smallThumbnail})` }}></div>
                    <BookShelfChanger
                      shelf={book.shelf ? book.shelf : 'none'}
                      onChangeShelf={(newShelf) => {
                        this.handleChange(book, newShelf)
                      }}
                    ></BookShelfChanger>
                  </div>
                  <div className="book-title">{book.title}</div>
                  <div className="book-authors">{book.authors}</div>
                </div>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Using a `setState` updater method in your empty query case is unnecessary, you can just use a `stateChange` object like you do in the search handler

Comment: It seems like your problem is not exactly that the `setState({result:[]})` is not getting run, but rather that both it and the result of the search are getting run on the same update cycle, and the search results are overwriting the empty result. To prevent this, you probably want to debounce your search handler, or at the very least have it differentiate between the "waiting for results" and "idle" states